# CSS link colors rendering differently from index.html on root URL

Tags: html, css

My drop down menu links are supposed to be light blue on hover. This happens fine on my index.html page. But when I go to the root URL for my site, they don't change from their standard color. I've tried adding !important but it doesn't work, and seems unnecessary since it works on index.html.

**Head tag:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Filthy Hippie, a Petz 3/4 fansite</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.gif">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
```

**Dropdown Menu CSS:**

```
    .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #502f2f;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #442828;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #e794ad;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.visited {
  color: #e794ad;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #502f2f;
  color: #d69494;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 20px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #e794ad;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #442828;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #502f2f;
  color: #efdec6;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #efdec6;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #502f2f;
  color: #d69494;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #502f2f;
  color: #c6e7e7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:visited {
  background-color: #502f2f;
  color: #efdec6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;
  display: block;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

[Correct on index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efnk7.jpg)
[Incorrect on root url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0VK2.jpg)

Comment: Does it happen after clicking the links?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the correct CSS is being loaded? If you look in your browser devtools inspect facility what style settings are there for Calico? Have you cleared your browser cache to force a reload of any files?

Comment: After a bit of fiddling and thinking I realized my CSS was out of order, and my other link styles were overriding my .dropdown-content a:hover style. I needed to move my .dropdown-content a:hover style to the bottom, and sort my link styles by order of importance from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0):

My CSS is out of order, and my other link styles are overriding my .dropdown-content a:hover style. I need to move my .dropdown-content a:hover style below my other link styles, and sort my link styles by order of importance from the bottom up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).